# Analysing data from World of Warcraft API

Tags: python, pandas

Wanted to perform a weekly analysis on World of Warcraft Mythic Keystone runs from Bizzard game api.
The content type is in json format. Tried to read it with pandas dataframe but got error message. Could anyone help? Thanks a million.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected-realm/11/mythic-leaderboard/197/period/641?namespace=dynamic-us&locale=en_US&access_token=USv4TApalDNvvoTftKi4ieXKafqA0UkxM5"
df = pd.read_json(url)
print(df)

> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b30c467d73f5> in <module>
      4 
      5 url = "https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected-realm/11/mythic-leaderboard/197/period/641?namespace=dynamic-us&locale=en_US&access_token=USv4TApalDNvvoTftKi4ieXKafqA0UkxM5"
----> 6 df = pd.read_json(url)
      7 print(df)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    297                 )
    298                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 299             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    300 
    301         return wrapper

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression, nrows, storage_options)
    561 
    562     with json_reader:
--> 563         return json_reader.read()
    564 
    565 
......
```

Comment: The issue is this is a complex nested data structure.  Have you looked into particular data you want to extract from this data structure?  Pandas Dataframe are usually from a simple 2D table structure (i.e. multiple rows with an equal number of columns on each row).

Answer (score 0):

For complex data I would use simple data structure (`list`/`dict`), but If you want load it to Pandas DataFrame, you can use this example (uses `pd.json_normalize()`):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected-realm/11/mythic-leaderboard/197/period/641?namespace=dynamic-us&locale=en_US&access_token=USv4TApalDNvvoTftKi4ieXKafqA0UkxM5"
data = requests.get(url).json()

# explode leading_groups
df = pd.json_normalize(data).explode("leading_groups")
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df["leading_groups"].apply(pd.Series),
        df.drop(columns="leading_groups"),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ranking  duration  completed_timestamp  keystone_level                                            members  period  period_start_timestamp  period_end_timestamp                                   keystone_affixes  map_challenge_mode_id            name                                   _links.self.href        map.name  map.id                               connected_realm.href
0        1   4701656        1523646535000              25  [{'profile': {'name': 'Volladin', 'id': 186986...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0        2   2810578        1523583162000              23  [{'profile': {'name': 'Noru', 'id': 180317150,...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0        3   3011261        1523943629000              23  [{'profile': {'name': 'Poodz', 'id': 129866206...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0        4   1893872        1523401897000              22  [{'profile': {'name': 'Stigflow', 'id': 183169...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0        5   1910501        1523540964000              22  [{'profile': {'name': 'Royally', 'id': 1842199...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0        6   2003593        1523424537000              22  [{'profile': {'name': 'Orhdanett', 'id': 17475...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0        7   2083673        1523688943000              22  [{'profile': {'name': 'Aiery', 'id': 156862476...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0        8   2365147        1523496642000              22  [{'profile': {'name': 'Illidannqt', 'id': 1830...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0        9   1660092        1523518737000              21  [{'profile': {'name': 'Shanko', 'id': 18509440...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0       10   1996725        1523733590000              21  [{'profile': {'name': 'Plainspoon', 'id': 1580...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0       11   2000433        1523781862000              21  [{'profile': {'name': 'Drnkdds', 'id': 1850621...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0       12   2022052        1523920103000              21  [{'profile': {'name': 'Shùgo', 'id': 177712580...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0       13   2117574        1523923657000              21  [{'profile': {'name': 'Blindeyess', 'id': 1880...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0       14   2189980        1523836760000              21  [{'profile': {'name': 'Webangel', 'id': 182353...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0       15   2282325        1523412562000              21  [{'profile': {'name': 'Forbídden', 'id': 13204...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0       16   2308561        1523951532000              21  [{'profile': {'name': 'Typicaltimm', 'id': 185...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0       17   2416497        1523844384000              21  [{'profile': {'name': 'Slashtro', 'id': 173303...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0       18   2686569        1523529099000              21  [{'profile': {'name': 'Trexboi', 'id': 1591660...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0       19   2779084        1523526569000              21  [{'profile': {'name': 'Shunellx', 'id': 181652...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...
0       20   3025735        1523486505000              21  [{'profile': {'name': 'Palymon', 'id': 1791935...     641           1523372400000         1523977199000  [{'keystone_affix': {'key': {'href': 'https://...                    197  Eye of Azshara  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...  Eye of Azshara    1456  https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/connected...

...and so on.
```